# Testing successful payment from Google Pay with Paysafe?

Tags: paysafe

So, I'm using Paysafe as my payment processor, and they only allow certain card numbers for testing successful transactions. I cannot add these card numbers to my Google account (I get an error that tells me to correct the card number), so it seems that I can't test successful transactions with Google Pay/Paysafe?
When Google Pay is in TEST environment, they say they don't charge cards (even if it's a real card). So would I have to put Paysafe into it's production environment to be able to test a successful transaction with Google Pay, or has anyone gotten around this?
When I send the token from Google Pay to the Paysafe TEST environment, I get this error:

Either the payment token is invalid or the corresponding profile or credit card is not active

But I know I'm getting the right token and sending it properly (since it's a test environment the token is always the same though), so I figure since the Google Pay TEST token card number isn't one of the accepted Paysafe testing card numbers, I'll have to put Paysafe into production and then test Google Pay? Again, if anyone has found a way around this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically, you passed your own credit card in Google Pay. You implemented added Paysafe has the gateway and passed the SUT key encoded. 
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorialYou 
You got the GooglePaymentToken back and you generated the paysafe token via https://developer.paysafe.com/en/vault/api/#/reference/single-use-tokens/create-a-google-pay-single-use-token. You are now trying to use that token to process a payment the Cards API?